# R - Pass element of list as argument to function call

Tags: r, parameters

Let's start with some simple code:

```
require(randomForest)
randomForest(mpg~.,mtcars,ntree=10)
```

This builds a random forest of 10 trees.

What I want is to store the parameter in a list in than make the function call. Something like this:

```
require(randomForest)
l<-list(ntree=10)
randomForest(mpg~.,mtcars,l[[1]])
```

However, this does not work. The error message is:

```
Error in if (ncol(x) != ncol(xtest)) stop("x and xtest must have same number of columns") : argument is of length zero
```

This indicates that the parameter xtest=NULL of randomForest is set to 10 instead of ntree.

Why is that? How can I pass the parameter ntree as a list element?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. It does, but I want to specify in the list which parameter should be  set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `do.call` to accomplish this, although you will have to adjust how you input the arguments.

```
do.call(randomForest, list(formula=as.formula(mpg~.), data=mtcars, ntree=10))
```

The printed output is not as pretty, but at the end, you get

```
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 10
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

          Mean of squared residuals: 9.284806
                    % Var explained: 73.61
```

and if you save the returned object, it will have the same values as if you typed it in.

You can store the list ahead of time as well

```
l <- list(formula=as.formula(mpg~.), data=mtcars, ntree=10)
myForest <- do.call(randomForest, l)
```